# HOW TO ADD THE SOURCE OF ROWS AS ANOTHER COLUMN WHILE USING UNION IN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Select Sid,Sname from Salesman
Union all
Select prodId, Category from Product
```

In the above SQL code,I want to add another column in the resulting table named TYPE which stores S for rows from Salesman Table and P for rows from Product table.

Can anyone help!

Answer (score 3):

Just add it explicitly:

```
Select Sid, Sname, 'Sales' as source from Salesman
Union all
Select prodId, Category, 'Product'
from Product;
```